# How do you re-specify the current step_queue using a Python script

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the code similar to: self.client.sendgoal(walkgoal) used in the Keyboard Teleop example that sends only an updated set of steps while the BDI continues to actively execute a step list.  Do we need to specify where in the list of 4 steps these numbered steps need to be inserted?  Can we specify steps further out then the 4 steps that the controller is holding?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2740/how-do-you-re-specify-the-current-step_queue-using-a-python-script/) by [eric](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/341/eric/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can only specify the next 4 steps, and you can know when there is another needed by looking at the "`/atlas/atlas_sim_interface_state`" message which specifies "`walk_feedback`" which has the field "`next_step_index_needed`":

- https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/default/ros/atlas_msgs/msg/AtlasBehaviorWalkFeedback.msg?at=default

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0